# Как закруглить фоновое изображение?

Tags: css

Как закруглить углы у background-image? Есть-ли какое-нибудь свойство?

Comment: Если вам не подходит `border-radius` — уточните вопрос, объяснив, почему он вам не подходит. Покажите ваши текущие HTML и CSS, в которых нужно закруглить фон

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ss {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://www.igrotime.ru/upload/t/800-700/large_foto/kartina-po-nomeram-cvetnye-chuvstva-gx4759.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ss">
</div>
```

Comment: Мне не подходит такой вариант.

Comment: @PavelBogdanov тогда внесите корректировки в вопрос. Критерии например. Я ж не Ванга чтобы понять что подходит а что нет :)

Comment: вы можете перенести это изображение в псевдоэлемент ::after или ::before, тогда у основного элемента останутся углы прямоугольные

Answer (score 1):

С помощью свойства CSS - `border-radius`  вы можете дать любому элементу «закругленные углы».

> ```
> .round {
>   /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
>   -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
>
>   /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
>   -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
>
>   /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
>   border-radius: 12px; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это делается с помощью `style="border-radius: ...px"`, например:

```
<button style="width: 120; height: 120"><img src="https://kor.ill.in.ua/m/100x100/1761802.jpg" style="border-radius: 50px; width: 100; height: 100"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам дали ответ на поставленный вопрос:

> "Есть-ли какое-нибудь свойство?"

Ответ:

> С помощью свойства CSS - border-radius вы можете дать любому элементу «закругленные углы».

Если вам не подходит такое решение, то на вопрос:

> Как закруглить углы у background-image?

Я даю свой ответ:

Никак.